# How to disable the Android keyboard from taking the control over input fields in webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-softkeyboard, android-source

I have been working on this specific requirement for more than 2 months now. But I haven't found a solution yet to disable the native keyboard when an input field is focused in a webview. I am building an app which has a built in keypad(essentially a view) and I want this to be displayed instead of the native keyboard.

What I've tried so far:

1. Add javascript eventListener for click events to display my keypad
   using JavscriptInterface.(Works)
2. Set the webview focusable:false and
   its parent's `descendantFocusability` to  `blocksDescendants` (This works
   but doesn't display the cursor on the input field)
3. Hiding the native
   keyboard on resize event of javascript using loadUrl method.(Works
   but the native keyboard is displayed momentarily before hiding the
   keyboard)
4. Listening to the `OnGlobalLayoutChange` event to check if 
   the keyboard has been added. (Works but the result is same as
   in the case above with a little improve in performance)
5. Force stop the IME service. (Works but the app has to be a system
   app to force stop packages and the keyboard service has to be started 
   whenever the app goes to background.
   Is there a way in which I can make this work?

Comment: have you added your keyboard from setting. then only your keyboard should display.

Comment: have you implemented http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12344049/3496570

Comment: When I say keypad its a keypad as in a view which shows the keys.

Comment: try this https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

Comment: @Nepster in that library the dev is using the onGlobalLayoutListener approach which means he's first invoking the keyboard and then adding the Emoji layout. The keyboard is being displayed their as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the [windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) to `stateAlwaysHidden` for the `Activity` containing the web view. This should keep the onscreen keyboard hidden for the entirety of that `Activity`.

Comment: But that will not show the cursor right? I need the cursor to be shown.

Comment: I don't believe that will have any impact on the cursor but I'm not positive. From my understanding of that flag it only impacts if the keyboard is shown when the window has focus, not changing the actual focus behavior.

Comment: Actually the documentation of that flag is misleading. It only hides the keyboard when the window has focus. Like avoiding the keyboard to show in case you have an edittext in you layout. But once the edittext gains focus it shows the keyboard.